# testing backbone with the jasmine gives "NetworkError: 404 Not Found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, jasmine

I am using backbone-on-rails and jasmine gem

spec file in spec/javascript

test_spec.js.coffee

```
describe "test backbone script", ->
  it "check the back bone form loaded on the container div", ->
    expect($("#container").text()).not.toEqual('back bone test')
```

routes

```
resources :demos
```

assets/javascripts/routers

```
class BackboneDemo.Routers.Backbonescripts extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'

    initialize: ->
      @collection = new BackboneDemo.Collections.Backbonescripts()
      @collection.fetch()
```

assets/javascripts/model

```
 class BackboneDemo.Collections.Backbonescripts extends Backbone.Collection
   url: '/demos'
   model: BackboneDemo.Models.Backbonescript
```

when I do rake jasmine

on localhost:8888/

the response is

File not found: `/demos`

error comes `404 Not Found`

the backbone is sending the request /demos to demo controller but response is not coming

on localhost:3000/ backbone script is working fine

Comment: maybe you should try `localhost:8888/demos` as the url?

Comment: Have a look at the logs genereted by jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine runs its own server and doesn't actually boot your rails app. This means that your rails routes (e.g. `/demos`) don't exist when running jasmine tests. You can use [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) to mock out the ajax requests that backbone makes with fake responses to make the tests run.